# Piramide de Numeros -> C++

Tags: c++

Necesito Ayuda.
Tengo que imprimir una pirámide de números. Ya eh intentado varias opciones. El problema esta en que la forma en como se debe imprimir es un poco compleja. El programa pide "n" numero. Por ejemplo en caso de que sea n=6, debe imprimir esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo eh intentado me imprime solo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me aparecen los espacios, y tampoco la pirámide superior invertida. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer?
Les muestro mi código.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int i,j,numero;
 cout<<"Ingrese numero"<<endl;
 cin>>numero;
 cout<<endl;
 for( i=1;i<=numero; i++){
     for(j=1; j<=i;j++){
         cout<<j;
     }
     cout<<endl;
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Pues la parte invertida de la pirámide es hacer lo que haces ya pero en el orden inverso y antes de lo que ya haces. Ahí se resuelve lo primero. Para los espacios, revisa cuántos espacios necesitas a cada lado de cada fila; ahí ya puedes implementar código que haga eso para cada fila que imprimas, en función del número de elementos que tenga la pirámide

Answer (score 2):

Puedes imprimir un número acotado de espacios usando uno de los constructores de la clase `std::string`:

```
std::cout << std::string(11, 'a'); // imprime aaaaaaaaaaa
```

Vemos que la cantidad de espacios empieza en cero y llega a seis para al final volver a cero, es la misma progresión que siguen los números: cuenta hasta seis, cuenta uno menos por cada línea hasta contar sólo uno y después aumenta hasta llegar a seis de nuevo.

¿Existe una función matemática que tenga un comportamiento así? Efectivamente:
[Valor absoluto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valor_absoluto):

[image]

Podemos hacer un recuento que siga la estructura de la pirámide que necesitas:

```
for (int indice = -5, linea = 0; indice != 6; ++indice, ++linea)
    std::cout << "Linea " << linea << ' '
              << (6 - std::abs(indice)) << " espacios, contar hasta: "
              << (std::abs(indice) + 1) << '\n';
```

El código anterior, muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Linea 0 1 espacios, contar hasta: 6
> Linea 1 2 espacios, contar hasta: 5
> Linea 2 3 espacios, contar hasta: 4
> Linea 3 4 espacios, contar hasta: 3
> Linea 4 5 espacios, contar hasta: 2
> Linea 5 6 espacios, contar hasta: 1
> Linea 6 5 espacios, contar hasta: 2
> Linea 7 4 espacios, contar hasta: 3
> Linea 8 3 espacios, contar hasta: 4
> Linea 9 2 espacios, contar hasta: 5
> Linea 10 1 espacios, contar hasta: 6
> ```

Si creamos una función que cree una cadena con los números separados por espacio y aprovechando el constructor de `std::string`, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

std::string numeros_hasta(int numero)
{
    std::string result;

    for (int indice = 0; indice != numero; ++indice)
    {
        result.push_back('1' + indice);
        result.push_back(' ');
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for (int indice = -5; indice != 6; ++indice)
        std::cout << std::string(6 - std::abs(indice), ' ')
                    << numeros_hasta(std::abs(indice) + 1) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Que muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 
>  1 2 3 4 5 
>   1 2 3 4 
>    1 2 3 
>     1 2 
>      1 
>     1 2 
>    1 2 3 
>   1 2 3 4 
>  1 2 3 4 5 
> 1 2 3 4 5 6
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNroIwEEbX9CnGuGgJYnRxWQj6JCamll5phIH0Z2V8diwUFb13135zpnOmoutSUXO89P1SoahdKaFQrbFa8uZA3plPFF7miWi4rQ6EGFvudqEM6BqpW3OquLGcKbRTEpMbieaglsbVNick@m01jKTCUgkJe9jkz/NiP/XnkCQhi0nkn4pC/7pzpjqdubgyuqWQTH1x/i8BdCjc/UwtrdP4kvDRINBwhWw0/euU/sylsg@fsJhonYWigNmWLIM03PnZsIlfwSAykJ@f9c35bbYjRo9IvffLeuOF@/4B)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

A  tu código solo le falta una segunda iteración  a la inversa de la primera. En el  código pongo los comentarios:

```
   
int main()
{
    int i, j, numero;
    cout << "Ingrese numero" << endl;
    cin >> numero;
    cout << endl;


    // Primera Iteración. Va de  0 al numero  ingresado pero sin incluirlo
    // El primer for son las lineas que se imprimiran. 
    for (i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
       // Calcula cuanto espacio  a la derecha se debe dejar. 
       // Los espacios a las derecha es el valor de i + 1
        cout.width(i+1); 
        cout << " ";
        // Este  for  imprime los números de 1 al numero ingresado
        for (j=0;j<(numero-i); j++) {
            cout.width(2);
            cout.fill(' ');
            cout << std::left << j+1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

   // Segunda Iteració. Imprime el arbol invertido. Es exactamente la inversa del for anterioer 

    for (i = (numero-1); i>0;i--) {
        cout.width(i);
        cout << " ";
        for (j = 0; j < (numero - i  + 1 ); j++) {
            cout.width(2);
            cout.fill(' ');
            cout << std::left << j + 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Venía por los mismo pero ya me salió y bueno dejo mi solución por si a alguien le sirve :D

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, k = 1;

    do {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n <= 0 || n > 10); //restriccion

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) //triangulo invertido superior
    {
        for (j = n - 2; j >= n - i; j--) //empuja el medio triangulo inv. dandole la forma de uno entero
        {
            cout << " ";
        }

        for (j = n; j >= i; j--) //medio triangulo inv.
        {
            cout << k << " ";
            k++;
        }
        k = 1;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) //triangulo inferior
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) //empuja el medio triangulo dandole la forma de uno entero
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) //medio triangulo
        {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Una solución:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printRow(int n, int spaces) {
    std::cout << std::string(spaces, ' ');
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; --i) {
        printRow(i, n - i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        printRow(i, n - i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Considera explicar la solución detalladamente para que otros usuarios puedan comprenderla